# Need to convert string to DateTime format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, string-to-datetime

I have a string stored in table `"13/12/1985 12:00:00 a.m."` when i tried to convert this to Datetime, i am getting an exception saying "String is not a valid DateTime Format". It is because the first part of the `string(13)` is month. Is there any way to convert the above string to (`mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm`) format?. Actually the string saved in table is in the format of "dd/mm/yyyy". I want to convert to "mm/dd/yyyy" in Datetime

Comment: Another question: why do you store a `DateTime` as `string` in your table? You would avoid this exception and other issues if you'd store it as what it is.

Comment: @DHN, that link is for `python`, but this question is for `C#`.  I'm positive there's answers for C# though

Comment: @TimSchmelter that is an existing table. And that table has seperate column to store Datatype. Say DateTime as 'D'. If it is D then i need to convert to datetime

Comment: @user3403111: why do you store the type in a separate column? Don't store everything as string/nvarchar and convert it clientside. Instead use the correct type in the first place.

Comment: So you've built a database engine in a database engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, its convert `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format datetime to `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt` format

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("26/04/2016 12:00:00 PM", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string newdate = dt.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: i want mm/dd/yyyy format

Comment: And did you try using that format? Please note that `mm` means minutes and `MM` means months.

Comment: @user3403111 in c# `MM `is month and `mm` is minute, so I guess you want month right ?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yeah that is month. Sorry